# Chartjs mixed bar/line chart bars widths overlaps other columns

Tags: chart.js

I have date chart with a line and a bar datasets.

The problem that I have is that the bar widths is overlapping other columns as the bar dataset will be normally zero.

[image]

You can see that the two bars are overlapping with June 4 column.

If I add a bar value in two consecutives days, it will adjust correctly the bar width.

[image]

Now the bar widths adjusts for each day column.

If there are more days the bars widths get worst:

[image]

You can see that in this chart, it seems that the bars widths overlaps with 4 days in the x axys.

You can check an example code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKdjay?editors=1010

Uncomment the js code at line 38 to see how the bars width adjusts.

This is the code I use to initialize the chart.

```
new Chart($('#chart'), {
type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Reach",
        data: reachData,
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderWidth: 3,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-right',
        type: 'line'
      }, {
        label: "Interactions",
        data: interactionsData,
        borderColor: 'rgb(139, 195, 74)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(139, 195, 74)',
        borderWidth: 3,
        fill: false,
        xAxisId: 'x-axis',
        lineTension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    bezierCurve : false,
    tooltips: {
      position: 'nearest',
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'll'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
        id: 'y-axis-left',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "Reach",
          fontColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
        }
      }, {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
        id: 'y-axis-right',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "Interactions",
          fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```